# Why do I get Segmentation fault while calling function with variable as pointer to character array?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am new in using character array pointers. If I run code with main function 1 ,it run properly and prints "hello" word without any error .But in using second main function I get error as segmentation fault.

I am trying to find it out but don't understand what is the problem here. Actually my aim is to use 2nd main function with pointer to the character array(because I am having data in that form only). How do I execute code using 2nd main function to get same result as of main function 1?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void enmToStng(char varState[])
{
    strcpy(varState,"hello");
}
//main function 1
int main(void)
{
    char varState[]= {"1"};
    enmToStng(varState);
    printf("varState = %s\n", varState);
    return 0;   
}
//main function 2
/*int main(void)
{
    char *varState[]= {"1","2","3"};
    enmToStng(varState[1]);
    printf("varState[1] = %s\n", varState[1]);
    return 0;   
}*/
```

Comment: There is not enough space to copy in the six chars of "hello", hence out-of-bounds writes and UB:(

Comment: How big do you think `varState` is?  Correct, it's 2.  How many characters do you think `"hello"` requires?  Right again, it's 6 (5 + 1 terminating null character).  You're writing past your array. Don't do that.

Comment: There is no room for `"ello"` in `varState[]`.

Comment: @Tom Karzes ok .got your point .but any how I want to run 2nd main function and print the result "hello". From the below answer also , i get value printed as 2 not "hello". What addition is required then ?

Comment: @user3559780 Yeah, that answer is incomplete.  There are 2 ways you can handle this:  (1) You can pass in enough memory for `enmToStng` to do the copy in the memory it is provided, or (2) You can have `enmToStng` allocate the memory dynamically, e.g. with `malloc` or, better, with `strdup`.  If you go with the latter approach, then you need some way to return the newly allocated pointer to the caller.  You can do this by making it a `char *` function and returning it as a return value, or the caller can pass a `char **` argument whose target is modified by `enmToStng`.

Answer (score 0):

you declaring a string which have space only for two elements, (`1 and \0`) ,but then you are copying  `hello` 7 characters in it ,you can't do that because you don't have enough space.

you can use something like this

```
void enmToStng(char varState[])
{
    varState = malloc(7);
    strcpy(varState, "hello");
}
```

PS:since you are not sending `varState` by reference ,in `main` you will print `1` not `hello`.